# Getting the right node in Linq to XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

Im trying to parse an XML file containing all the uploaded videos on a certain channel. Im attempting to get tbe value of the URL attribute in one of the `<media:content>` nodes and put it in the ViewerLocation field. However there are several of them. My current code is this:

```
var videos = from xElem in xml.Descendants(atomNS + "entry")
select new YouTubeVideo()
{
    Title = xElem.Element(atomNS + "title").Value,
    Description = xElem.Element(atomNS + "content").Value,
    DateUploaded = xElem.Element(atomNS + "published").Value,
    ThumbnailLocation = xElem.Element(mediaNS + "group").Element(mediaNS + "content").Attribute("url").Value,
    ViewerLocation = xElem.Element(mediaNS + "group").Element(mediaNS + "content").Attribute("url").Value
};
```

It gets me the first node in the XML for entry with the name `<media:content>` as you would expect. However, the first entry in the XML isn't what  I want. I want the second.

Below is the relevant XML.

```
<!-- I currently get the value held in this node -->
<media:content 
  url='http://www.youtube.com/v/ZTUVgYoeN_b?f=gdata_standard...'
  type='application/x-shockwave-flash' medium='video'
  isDefault='true' expression='full' duration='215' yt:format='5'/>

<!-- What i actually want is this one -->
<media:content
  url='rtsp://rtsp2.youtube.com/ChoLENy73bIAEQ1kgGDA==/0/0/0/video.3gp'
  type='video/3gpp' medium='video'
  expression='full' duration='215' yt:format='1'/>

<media:content
  url='rtsp://rtsp2.youtube.com/ChoLENy73bIDRQ1kgGDA==/0/0/0/video.3gp'
  type='video/3gpp' medium='video'
  expression='full' duration='215' yt:format='6'/>
```

I want the second node because it has a type of 'video/3gpp'. How would I go about selecting that one? My logic would be

if attribute(type == "video/3gpp") get this value.

But i do not know how to express this in Linq.

Thanks,

Danny.

Answer (score 0):

Probably something like;

```
where xElem.Element(atomNS + "content").Attribute("type").Value == "video/3gpp"
```

Edit: I didn't quite know how to expand and explain this one without assuming the OP had no knowledge of Linq. You want to make your original query;

```
from xElem in xml.Descendants(atomNS + "entry") 
where xElem.Element(atomNS + "content").Attribute("type").Value == "video/3gpp"
select new YouTubeVideo() { 
  ...
}
```

You can interrogate attributes of a node, just like you can look at the elements of the document. If there are multiple elements with that attribute, you could then (assuming you always want the first you find)..

```
  ( from xElem in xml.Descendants(atomNS + "entry") 
    where xElem.Element(atomNS + "content").Attribute("type").Value == "video/3gpp"
    select new YouTubeVideo() { 
      ...
    }).First();
```

I changed the original post, as I believe the node you're querying is the Element(atomNS + "content"), not the top level xElem

Comment: Sorry about that, I wasn't sure at first how to expand.But it helped, being asked to because I think I made an error originally.

Comment: Adding the where cause now means that nothing is returned into the var :/

Comment: You mention in your post that it gets you the first entry, does that mean you were only ever getting back the first element, not all three? If that's the case, that's why you don't get anything back now, because you've discards that one result.

Comment: Basically just after this bit of linq i do an AddRange() into a list. The list used to be filled with items which had Title,
                            Description,
                            DateUploaded,
                            ThumbnailLocation,
                            ViewerLocation.
However the ViewerLocation just didnt have what I wanted in it. Now the list is empty and contains no Youtube Video Objects at all.

Answer (score 0):

Using XPath from this [Xml Library](https://github.com/ChuckSavage/XmlLib/) (Just because I know how to use it) with associated Get methods:

```
string videoType = "video/3gpp";

XElement root = XElement.Load(file); // or .Parse(xmlstring)
var videos = root.XPath("//entry")
    .Select(xElem => new YouTubeVideo()
    {
        Title = xElem.Get("title", "title"),
        Description = xElem.Get("content", "content"),
        DateUploaded = xElem.Get("published", "published"),
        ThumbnailLocation = xElem.XGetElement("group/content[@type={0}]/url", "url", videoType),
        ViewerLocation = xElem.XGetElement("group/content[@type={0}]/url", "url", videoType)
    });
```

If the video type doesn't change, you can replace the XGetElement's with:

```
xElem.XGetElement("group/content[@type='video/3gpp']/url", "url")
```

Its a lot cleaner not having to specify namespaces using the library.  There is the Microsoft's `XPathSelectElements()` and `XPathSelectElement()` you can look into, but they require you to specify the namespaces and don't have the nice `Get` methods imo.  The caveat is that the library isn't a complete XPath implementation, but it does work with the above.